# checkBoxList key value from CHtml::ListData

Tags: yii

$colors - model of colors: 'colorName' and colorCode(FFFFFF) 
('code'=>'FFFFFF', 'caption'=>'colorname')

```
    echo $form->checkBoxList($model, 'color', CHtml::listData($colors,'code','caption'),
        array(
            'template'=>'{label}{input}',
            'separator'=>'',
        )
    );
```

{label}  == 'colorname'
{input} - checkbox input

how I can use 'code' in checkboxList template??????

Comment: You cannot... Why do you need this ??

Comment: <div>
        <i style="background:#{color}"></i>{colorname}<input type="checkbox" name="colors[]">  
    </div>

Comment: You should write your own funtion for this kind of output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @soju said it's not possible to include both `colorname` and `colorcode` since the only sequences replaced in `template` are `{label}` and `{input}`. However if only common colours i.e white,grey,blue etc are the colour options you could just use the name instead of the colour code in the css.

```
echo $form->checkBoxList($model, 'color', CHtml::listData($colors,'code','caption'),
    array(
        'template'=>'<div><i style="background-color:{label}"></i>{label}{input}</div>',
        'separator'=>'',
    )
);
```